# Unity2d человек - человек на лошади, перемещение и закрепление на обьекте

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

Есть два вида управления, висят в одном скрипте на игроке
Один скрипт предназначен для ходьбы пешком, а другой для езды верхом
Пока что переключение между ними осуществляется просто на button("Action")(там все на ифах, не вижу смысла кидать скрипт управления)
В общем, не могу разобраться как реализовать не просто смену движение, а так чтобы персонаж вроде как забирался на лошадь(речь про скрипт - не анимации), как я понимаю, его нужно как-то перетащить на лошадь и закрепить, а потом слезть
Пытался реализовывать через триггер+родитель, но, то ли не разобрался, то ли где-то напортачил и он у меня так и не заработал
(вот тут бы пригодился скрипт, но я уже удалил этот кусок)

В интернете еще полазил ничего дельного не нашел, только то что иногда лучше для такого использовать distance, а не триггер для таких целей

Если делали нечто подобное не откажусь от фрагментов кода, но лучше, конечно, подскажите направление в котором двигаться, какие тут команды пригодятся, переместить ли мне управление лошадью на лошадь :D или лучше оставить на плеере(с учетом того, что предполагается еще повозка, но управление то же что и на лошади)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто перемести обьект лошади внутрь обьекта плеера в иерархии инспектора (кодом в необходимый момент). А потом размести на необходимой высоте обоих.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

А перемещать ли на лошади или на плеере - думаю что лучше оставить на плеере.

---

Вариант 2 -  джоинты, есть как оф.документация так и оф.туториалы:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4xikqJdkwM

Comment: а каким образом мне это поможет? 
Предлагаешь просто прятать лошадь, а потом ее колдовать?
Это можно использовать как временную меру, для демо, но мою проблему это никак не решит
Ты мне предлагаешь систему вроде дарксайдерс 2, а мне нужно как ведьмаке 3(это просто аналогии, не надо придираться)
У меня в игре лошадь такой же физический объект, как и персонаж и мне необходимо, чтобы она была отдельным объектом в мире, а не постоянно находилась под персонажем
А насчет документации... серьезно? =_= я, конечно, понимаю, что сам сказал, что не понял, но я знаю адрес документации, спасибо

Comment: ну если не нравится задавание парента, то тогда Joint-ы. Но лично я бы в этой таске использовал бы SetParent. Это самая простая привязка. Если ты сам знаешь адрес документации, то и Joint-ы мог бы сам найти, а не только SetParent :) Про прятать и колдовать вообще не понял. А в обе игры которые ты назвал я не играл и понятия не имею о чем ты говоришь. По поводу "а не постоянно находилась под персонажем" - вообще не отстреливаю о чем ты. Когда необходимо можно делать парентом, когда необходимо - снимать. При чем здесь постоянно?

Comment: Не верно выразился, я имел ввиду, что про родителя я уже читал и я писал о нем в вопросе, а так адрес документации то у меня есть, но я ж не всю ее читал, об этой команде ни разу не слышал, сейчас бегло чекнул и вроде это как раз то, что мне нужно, спасибо
Если есть какие-то команды, которые мне потенциально помогут, то буду не против списка(если не сложно)

P.S. я сейчас свой прошлый комент прочел и понял, что он каким-то агрессивным выглядит, сори эбаут зет

Comment: сет парента достаточно. Но если не понравится - как я писал выше - джоинты. Где документация ты знаешь)